# access a variable from callback function NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a simplified code of my payment service in node.js:

```
async function pay({ package, via }) {

    const options = {
        api: 'test',
        factorNumber: '123456789',
        description: `package-${package}`,
        redirect: 'http://localhost:4000/accounts/pay/callback', // this will hit router.get('/pay/callback', payCallback);
    }
    
    const response = await axios.post('https://pay.ir/pg/send', options, {
        headers: {'content-type': 'text/json'}
    });

    return { redirect: `https://pay.ir/pg/${response.data.token}` };

}

// this function is executed when we redirect to http://localhost:4000/accounts/pay/callback as I explained above
async function payCallback(req, res) {

   // how can I access 'via' here

}
```

As you see in the first function named `pay` I have access to `via` variable which is the email or phone number of the user who wants to pay, ok?

The payment API I'm using just allow the `options` in the `pay` function to be accessible from the `payCallback` (this one is a function which fires at successful payment).

But I need to know who paid and check the database to insert the new payment for the user right?

So I need to access `via` inside the `payCallback`...

How can I access `via` inside `payCallback` function?

Comment: How does `pay` get called? You could save `via` in `req` but for that you'd need `req` passed in...

Comment: which api are you using? you could modify `pay` to `return { via, redirect: ... }` but it's not clear how `pay` is called or what happens with the returned value. without knowing these details, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the required data would be sent by your payment API in the `payCallback`'s request body. Check their documentation.

If that isn't actually the case, you could insert the pending payment into a database with a unique ID, then add that unique ID to your redirect url:

```js
async function pay({ package, via }) {

    const paymentId = insertIntoDatabase(...);

    const options = {
        api: 'test',
        factorNumber: '123456789',
        description: `package-${package}`,
        redirect: `http://localhost:4000/accounts/pay/callback?paymentId=${paymentId}`,
    }

    const response = await axios.post('https://pay.ir/pg/send', options, {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'text/json' }
    });

    return { redirect: `https://pay.ir/pg/${response.data.token}` };

}

async function payCallback(req, res) {
    const { paymentId } = req.query;
    if (!paymentId) {
        // Unexpected, log an error or so. Tell customer to contact customer service
        return;
    }
    const paymentInfo = getFromDatabase(paymentId);
    if (!paymentInfo) {
        // Also unexpected, so again log the error and tell the customer to contact you
        return;
    }
    // Do whatever with paymentInfo
}
```

If strictly speaking you **only** need `via`, you could add that as a query parameter instead of working with a database. But when it comes to payments, having some logging is a good idea anyway.

Comment: this was my first guess for how things would probably work. nice answer